# Replacing || (concatenation) in a string

Tags: javascript

I have problem with replacing || char.

```
    str="Example || sentence";

    document.write(str.replace(/||/g, "+"));
// it gives me "+ +E+x+a+m+p+l+e+ +|+|+ +s+e+n+t+e+n+c+e+"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a regular expression operator, that behaves like an `or`. You need to escape it if you want to match it inside a String:

```
str = "Example || sentence";
document.write(str.replace(/\|\|/g, "+"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` symbol has special meaning in regular expressions. You have to escape it.

```
document.write(str.replace(/\|\|/g, '+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
str.replace( /\|\|/g, '+' )
```

The vertical bars have are special characters inside a regular expression pattern and they have to be escaped.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mN3ft/